# Insert page break when using "markdown-pdf" nodejs module?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, markdown

I'm using the node.js module "Markdown-PDF" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-pdf, version 9.0) to covert markdown to PDF, and I need to add a few page breaks to clean up the presentation in the PDF output.

I tried all the recommendations I could find on this and other forums, including inline HTML tags such as:

> `<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>`

And some CSS hacks, like applying page breaks to all div tags (as described here: http://forums.apricitysoftware.com/t/include-pdf-pagebreak-instructions-in-markdown/152).  None of these are working, all tags in the markdown (source) document appear in the PDF (output) document un-rendered.

Expected (ideal) behavior would be to add the page breaks to the markdown files, and have the PDF reflect the desired changes.  Something like this, within my markdown files:

*markdown text*
*markdown text*
*markdown text*
[page break command]
*markdown text*
*markdown text*
*markdown text*

Thanks in advance for any assistance or suggestions that anyone can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Got an assist from a friend and figured this out.  Markdown-pdf uses HTML5Boilerplate, so you can edit the index.html file, found here on my system:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/markdown-pdf/html5bp/index.html

I added the CSS described here: http://forums.apricitysoftware.com/t/include-pdf-pagebreak-instructions-in-markdown/152

And it worked.  Was able to include the HTML tags described in the post and force page breaks.  Success!

Answer (score 0):

The styled div tag you mentioned only works if the html parameter of remarkable object is set to true in options parameter:

```
var markdownpdf = require("markdown-pdf")
  , fs = require("fs")
let options = {
  paperFormat: "A4",
  paperOrientation: "landscape",
  remarkable: {
    html: true
  }
}
fs.createReadStream("teste.md")
  .pipe( markdownpdf( options))
  .pipe( fs.createWriteStream("document.pdf"))
```

In order to use a md marker (instead of using html div tag), I guess you should use preProcessMd and change a specific pattern to the styled div tag.

Hope I could offer some help!